# Is there a way to modify/disable the setup timer in TF2 as a server owner?

Tags: team-fortress-2, hosting

Not to be confused with the "waiting for players" timer or the "end of round" timer, the setup timer is the one where, during payload race, control point, or KOTH games, the attacking team is locked inside their spawn while the defending team gets the run of the map to set up turrets and otherwise prepare for the onslaught.

Is there a way a server owner can modify this timeout?

Comment: I know that capping a point during setup adds time to the setup timer instead of the round timer, so...maybe do whatever you would do to modify the round timer?

Comment: It'd require a server plugin, but I don't think one exists yet to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, there is no way to do this with VANILLA SourceMod or TF2 because it is a value stored within the map.

**However** you might be able to do something with [this](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=70793) using the functions (sm_settime + sm_addtime)

Cheers.